# Stretching text within a certain size box

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, letterspacing

I would like to stretch some text within a certain size box, say two inches (I'm not sure yet how large I want the box to be). I came across this example to stretch text across the entire page:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\ugg{}{.4em plus 1fill}{1em plus 2 fill}{2em plus 2fill minus.1em}

\begin{document}


\noindent\ugg{one two three\\four five six}

\end{document}
```

I'm wondering how I might modify it for my purposes. Or should I use something else altogether? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As for your Q, I would actually just use `graphicx` for this.  (Or are you going for more of a letterspacing alteration?)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the definition you had in a box of a specific width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}

\sodef\SOFillToBox{}
              {.4em plus 1fill}
              {1em plus 2 fill}
              {2em plus 2fill minus.1em}

\NewDocumentCommand\SpreadBox{O{2in}m}{%
  \makebox[#1]{\SOFillToBox{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\SpreadBox{hello world}

\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]